# Rust Rocket REST API

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I can not compile main.rs file. And in `probabilityofunitinjectorfail` I want to add random generated number 0-100.

error: cannot find function 'iginite' in create 'rocket'.

Here is main.rs:

```
#![feature(decl_macro)]
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;

#[get("/probabilityOfUnitInjectorFail")]
fn probabilityofunitinjectorfail() -> &'static str {
    "/probabilityOfUnitInjectorFail"
}

fn main() {
        rocket::ignite()
        .mount("/", routes![probabilityofunitinjectorfail])
        .launch();

}
```

Comment: You are mixing -isms from two different versions of Rocket: see [What is the difference between rocket::ignite() and rocket::build()?](/q/73717634/2189130)

Answer (score 1):

```
#![feature(decl_macro)]
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;
            
#[get("/probabilityOfUnitInjectorFail")]
    fn probabilityofunitinjectorfail() -> &'static str{
    "/probabilityOfUnitInjectorFail"
    }
#[launch]
    fn rocket() -> _ {
               rocket::build().mount("/", routes![probabilityofunitinjectorfail])
            }
```

In new version ignite() was changed to build()

Comment: This is mentioned in the 0.5.0-rc.2 changelog  https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#general